# Virtual Machine apache not available

Tags: apache, virtualbox

Hoping someone can help with this. I have other VM's that dont have problems, so I'm not sure where the problem lies. I dont have any running at the same time.
I CAN ssh in and scp both ways but I cant connect with the browser OR sqldeveloper. Worried more about the browser right now

```
Guest: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2450/httpd
```

On the host i am forwarding 8081 -> 8081
In httpd.conf I have the port set as 8081

Browser: localhost:8081
not working

```
hosts file (guest)
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost

hostsfile (host)
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

and....
apache is running.

```
apache    2700  0.0  0.2 393572 11252 ?        S    13:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd

apache    2701  0.0  0.2 393572 11252 ?        S    13:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about: `sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get your guest IP address and connect directly? On the guest

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

And then shove that into:

```
http://10.0.1.120:8081/
```